# Hex to integer when reading MIDI file

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, hex

This might be a simple question. I'm reading a binary MIDI file using Python 3 and I'm having problems understanding how to turn the hex value `\x00\x00\x00\x06` into an integer, as I don't know what to do with the slash `\`. To get this value I'm using:

```
with open("/path/to/midi/file.mid", "rb") as f:
    header_chunk = f.read(4)
    length = f.read(4)
```

`length` ends up having a bytes object with value `b"\x00\x00\x00\x06"`. This value can be the unpacked into the corresponding numbers using `struct.unpack("cccc", length)` but this returns a tuple with hexadecimal numbers containing the `\`, `(b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x06')`. Is there a built-in way to turn this numbers as they are, in bulk like in `length` or in an individual fashion, to integers without having to deal with the `\` manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure:

```
>>> length
b'\x00\x00\x00\x06'
>>> list(length)
[0, 0, 0, 6]
```

Note, if you access the individual elements of your `bytes` object, you get an `int` in return:

```
>>> length[0]
0
>>> length[1]
0
>>> length[2]
0
>>> length[3]
6
>>>
```